# Using bash to make sure one program has had time to start before starting another

Tags: bash, java, node.js

I have an issue with the following bash script:

```
#Install and start application
./gradlew assemble
java -jar bignibou-server/build/libs/bignibou-server.jar&

#Run end2end tests
node_modules/.bin/protractor bignibou-client/protractor.conf.js
```

The first part of the script start a java application and the second part run end2end tests on that java application.

The trouble is that the end2end tests run before the java application has really started properly.

Can the bash help me here? Using the `&` is the cause of my problem. What is the correct way to end the `java -jar` command?

Comment: If you want to start the test ASAP, I'd just busy-wait/poll until the servers port is open and responsive, possibly with some smallish interval to keep the reasonably CPU cool if your sever takes some seconds to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of `&` to background the first process is correct here, as I presume that `bignibou-server` needs to be running during your tests?

By far the simplest method of introducing a delay before initiating your tests is to use the sleep command:

```
./gradlew assemble
java -jar bignibou-server/build/libs/bignibou-server.jar &

sleep 60

node_modules/.bin/protractor bignibou-client/protractor.conf.js
```

This would add a delay of 60 seconds before your tests begin. See `man sleep` for more information.